# Remove from DOM elements based on array items - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have an array in JS that I loop through. I have 5 LI's and depending on the content of that array, (it can only contain max 5 items) it shows those LI's. I want to edit my function, so that it can also remove the LI's from the DOM.

HTML - (I have these by default as display:none"

```
<ul>
    <li id="li-1"></li>
    <li id="li-2"></li>
    <li id="li-3"></li>
    <li id="li-4"></li>
    <li id="li-5"></li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
var basketArray = ["li-1", "li-2", "li-3", "li-4", "li-5"];

for(var i = 0; i < $basketArray.length; i++) {
     var id = $basketArray[i];
     $('#'+id).fadeIn();
}
```

How can I edit the above, so say in basketArray there was only li-2 & li-3, li-1,li-4 & li-5 are removed from the DOM. basketArray changes on refresh.

Thanks for your help.

D

Comment: have a look at jquery's `remove` https://api.jquery.com/remove/ and `detach` https://api.jquery.com/detach/ methods

Comment: Hi Will, thanks for the comment - I have an understanding of the remove method, however I don't know how to incorporate it into my for loop.

Comment: I don't understand how you want to differentiate between li's you want to keep and ones you want to remove.

Comment: That really depends on the behavior you want, basically what logic determines which elements should be removed or not?

Comment: Also, you don't need that for loop. a little bit of string manipulation would turn it into a 1liner.

Comment: So I want to remove any LI ID that doesn't match or feature in the array.

Comment: can you empty your UL and then repopulate it from scratch each time?

Comment: It will contain different data each time, so it could contain an ID referencing one List item or 5 of them.

Comment: that's the point; you empty your <ul> an then you repopulate it with the new IDs

Comment: The ul stays the same, that will always have 5 list items inside it, the array changes however.

Comment: I just want to remove the list items that aren't inside the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

loop your LIs, and use indexOf to check if the id is not in array.

```
var basketArray = ["li-1", "li-3", "li-4", "li-5"];


jQuery('ul li').each( function() {
    if( basketArray.indexOf( jQuery(this).attr('id') ) < 0)
        jQuery(this).remove();
});
```

Here's a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/s847s4se/